# How to handle a UIView's control events from a UIViewController.

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have subclassed a `UIView`. I am adding it as a subview of a `UIViewController` view. I have a button in the `UIView`. What I want is to handle the button click inside my `UIViewController`, where I will remove the `UIView` from superview and push another `UIViewController`. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must attach the target with your UIButton. **addTarget** method is used for getting the event when you click on button and defined in `UIControl` class which is direct super class of `UIButton`

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

Code to receive the event for Button touch.

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Implementation for the action.

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(id) sender {
  UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*)sender;
  //Put your code here 
}
```

Comment: I am confused about, what code should I add in my `UIView` and what in my `UIViewController`

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should create the button in the `UIViewController` and then add it to `UIView`

Comment: Whether you add the button in `UIView` or `UIViewController` View it doesn't matter BUT set 'UIViewController' instance as target and implement `buttonClicked:` in your UIViewController class ...